# Append select items from one nested dictionary to another

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, append

I am looking to append list items from one nested dictionary to another (From SystemDicto3 to SystemDictu4). They both have the same kind of content, the system number (Keys) and which emails (Values) fall under that system number. So far I have the following code (snippet of full code):

```
#Gets the key/system with the lowest amount of values/emails, set = to SysMin
SysLength = defaultdict(list)
for x in SystemDict:
    length = len(SystemDict[x])
    SysLength[x].append(length) 
SysMin = min(SysLength, key=SysLength.get)

for system in SystemDicto3: #Iterates through systems
    for item in SystemDicto3[system]: #iterates through emails within systems
        if item in system != SystemDictu4[system]: #if the email isn't in the dict, add it
            SystemDictu4.append(item)
```

I want to iterate over the SystemDicto3 dictionary emails (dfo3 dataframe was used to create this dictionary), adding the contents to the alreay populated SystemDictu4 dictionary based on which system it is in and prioritizing the system with the lowest count.

For example if the email "test1@test.com" is in (SystemDicto3):

```
 ['System 1']
 ['System 3']
 ['System 5'] 
 ['System 7']
```

I want to append that email to the three lowest SystemDictu4 systems. So if the length in SystemDictu4 is as follows:

```
system 1 = 100 
system 3 = 40 
system 5 = 200 
system 7 = 90
```

I want to append that email to systems 1, 3, and 7.

I have not included my full code, as it may complicate the question. Any help will be appreciated, and thank you for taking the time to read this!

The dictionaries look like the below code. There can be up to 60 systems, and 1000s of emails in each and the same email can show up across different systems, and my goal is to add the emails from the second dictionary to the first. the expected output would be a one populated dictionary, and one dictionary containing emails that were not sent to the first one.

```
    {'System 1':                         test1@test.com
                                       test2@test.com
                                       test5@test.com

'System 2':                                test1@test.com
                                           test7@test.com
                                           test55@test.com

 'System 3':                              test1@test.com
                                          test23@test.com
                                          test55@test.com

'System 4':                                test1@test.com
                                           test23@test.com
                                           test55@test.com   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets convert the dictionary of lists into a dictionary of sets.

```
SystemDictu4 = {'System 1': ['test1@test.com', 'test2@test.com', 'test5@test.com'],
                'System 2': ['test1@test.com', 'test7@test.com', 'test55@test.com'],
                'System 3': ['test1@test.com', 'test23@test.com', 'test55@test.com'],
                'System 4': ['test1@test.com', 'test23@test.com', 'test55@test.com']}
System = {k,set(v) for k,v in SystemDictu4.items()}
```

I recommend using a set since you will only need a single instance of each email address per system key. Once we have the larger system converted to a dictionary of sets, then we can use the nature of a set to unite the information from other systems.

```
def add_dict(SystemDictFrom, SystemDictTo, number_of_systems):
    for system in sorted(SystemDictFrom, key = lambda a: len(SystemDictFrom.get(a)))[:number_of_systems]:
        if system in SystemDictTo:
            SystemDictTo[system].union(SystemDictFrom[system])
        else:
            SystemDictTo[system] = SystemDictFrom[system]
```

In the function above, I'm using SystemDictFrom as the dictionary of lists or sets that will add values to the larger dictionary, SystemDictTo.

You might call that function with the following:

```
# This will add the three least populated systems from SystemDicto3 to SystemDictu4
add_dict(SystemDicto3, SystemDictu4, 3)
```

Comment: If you give me an example of input (a dictionary) and expected output, I'll add some code to my answer.

Comment: I added some more content, if you have any specific questions please let me know.

Comment: Would the following be an accurate representation of the dictionary you gave: {'System 1': ['test1@test.com', 'test2@test.com', 'test5@test.com'], 'System 2': ['test1@test.com', 'test7@test.com', 'test55@test.com'], 'System 3': ['test1@test.com', 'test23@test.com', 'test55@test.com'], 'System 4': ['test1@test.com', 'test23@test.com', 'test55@test.com']}

Comment: Yes exactly, the two dictionaries do have different sets of emails. So I am looking to add the contents of the smaller second dictionary to the first dictionary, keeping in mind that the emails added must transfer to the correct system, and must prioritize the 3 systems with the lowest count (SysMin variable)

Comment: Thank you, I have a much better idea of what you need now. Give me a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166052/discussion-between-mike-peder-and-bemurr187).